# IE9 bug - it doesn't apply style (all other browsers do)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, debugging, internet-explorer-9

Can someone debug slideshow on this website for me in IE9? http://millerwhite.net/~m360s/

I already managed to discover that buttons in slideshow are causing it to break because they are missing style in IE9 altogether (although style is present in source code!). You can see this in source code: `#slide_0 .button` but it doesn't apply any styles to buttons.

Chrome - OK
Firefox - OK
Safari - OK
iPhone - OK
iPad - OK
IE9 - Broken

Surprisingly it works on original website (both share the same files): http://themes.devatic.com/daisho/?prj=classic

IE9 debugger (F12) may show the style at the beginning but as soon as you change anything in it - it forgets entire style for all buttons...

One more thing:
When I reduce `<style>` tags in `<head>` to very low number - it starts working. Is there any limit in IE9?

Comment: there is a limit of 32 styles per page in IE. I am guessing that IE10 finally dropped this limitation

Comment: I've already resolved this by moving style to style.css but thanks for your information (this should be an accepted answer to this question if that's really true).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that IE9 doesn't allow more than 31 styles to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried replacing the id #slide_0 with non numbered like #styleT??